# duplicate id being generated in an id auto generate code in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Hi have created a program that reads last row of table and generate an id number according to the last generated id number, but still program is generating a duplicate id number that already in the table.
 my code is as :follow

```
private void get_code()
        {
                try
                {
                    con = new OleDbConnection(c.connectionstring);
                    con.Open();
                    string sql = "select code from bookings";
                    adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adp.Fill(ds, "BOOKINGS");
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        int ctr, len;
                        string codeval;
                        DataRow dr;
                        DataTable dt;
                        string code;
                        dt = ds.Tables["bookings"];
                        len = dt.Rows.Count -1;
                        dr = dt.Rows[len];
                        code = dr["code"].ToString();
                        codeval = code.Substring(2, 3);
                        ctr = Convert.ToInt32(codeval);
                        if ((ctr >= 1) && (ctr < 9))
                        {
                            ctr = ctr + 1;
                            Code.Text= "B-00" + ctr;
                        }
                        else if ((ctr >= 9) && (ctr < 99))
                        {
                            ctr = ctr + 1;
                            Code.Text = "B-0" + ctr;
                        }
                        else if (ctr >= 99)
                        {
                            ctr = ctr + 1;
                            Code.Text = "B-" + ctr;
                        }

                    }
                else
                {
                    Code.Text= "B-001";
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Occured : "+ex.Message,"Tailor Master",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
    }
```

in the following the scenario is like that : 
if the last id was b-005 it will again generated the same.

Please help to Solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Harish sharma

Comment: Disregarding whatever's wrong with the code, have you considered what might happen if two copies of your program run at very similar times?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify an `order by` clause in your query, so there's no guarantee that the last row of the data table contains the highest id.  There's also the general problem of generating ids in your application rather than using a proper auto-increment field in the database.